# Javascript - Toggle html5 required="" attribute based on form selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that's almost complete but I can't figure out the last piece.  The Javascript makes the check box appear or disappear based on the drop down selection (this is working great).  But I'm trying to make the check box "Required" if the checkbox is present (the part I can't figure out).

I'm using the htm5 `required=""` attribute on the check box field, but the form still tries to validate it even with the 3rd option selected, which hides the check box altogether.

Is there a way to toggle on/off the `required=""` in coordination with the selection of the drop down, or any other suggestions?

```
<script>    
   function getTerms(select){
        var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if(selectedString == "1" || selectedString == "2")
        {
            document.getElementById("terms_target").style.display = "block";
        }else {
            document.getElementById("terms_target").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="process_affiliate.php" method="post" onchange="getTerms(this)" >
<select name="InquiryType" required="">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Inquiry Type</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<div id="terms_target" style="display:none;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="Checked" required="" />I agree to the terms
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How is your function being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a newer version using addEventListener

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const sel = document.querySelector("[name=InquiryType]"),
    terms = document.getElementById("terms_target"),
    form = document.getElementById("myForm"),
    agree = form.checked; // checked is a poor name for a field
  toggleAgree = () => {
    const show = ["1", "2"].includes(sel.value);
    terms.hidden = !show;
    agree.required = show;
  };
  sel.addEventListener("change", toggleAgree)
  toggleAgree(); // initialise
})
```

```html
<form action="process_affiliate.php" id="myForm" method="post">
  <select name="InquiryType" required>
    <option value="">Please Select Your Inquiry Type</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <div id="terms_target" hidden>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="Checked" required="" />I agree to the terms
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Older version

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var sel = document.getElementsByName("InquiryType")[0];
  sel.onchange=function() {
    var selectedString = this.value,
        show = selectedString == "1" || selectedString == "2",
        terms = document.getElementById("terms_target"),
        checked=document.getElementsByName("checked")[0];
    terms.style.display = show?"block":"none";
    if (show) checked.setAttribute("required","required");
    else checked.removeAttribute("required");
  }
  sel.onchange(); // initialise
}
```

```html
<form action="process_affiliate.php" method="post">
<select name="InquiryType" required="">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Inquiry Type</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<div id="terms_target" style="display:none;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="Checked" required="" />I agree to the terms
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `terms.setAttribute("required",true)` is invalid because [`required`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute). Use `terms.setAttribute("required","")` or `terms.setAttribute("required","required")`. Or even better, use the IDL attribute instead: `terms.required = show`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I have no validation on the checkbox with this.  The form is allowed to submit without the check mark, which it shouldn't.

Comment: You have onchange on the form, not on the select. I had required on the div, not the checked box